# MSMQ service not starting after restart (error code -1072824319)

Tags: service, windows-service, msmq

Sometimes message queuing service do not start on startup. And when I try to start it manually (from services.msc), the following error comes:

> "Windows could not start Message Queuing on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code -1072824319".

I have googled this error code but could not find any information and that specific is not in the documentation on [Message Queuing Error and Information Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700106(v=vs.85).aspx) either.

Please tell me how to resolve this issue permanently, because I need to reinstall MSMQ everytime when I restart my windows 7 pc to fix this issue temporarily. I have also asked this question on [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-winapps/msmq-service-not-starting-after-restart-error-code/1a9db91e-d29f-4152-accf-49f7822ddcd5)

Comment: Unfortunately -1072824319 is 0xc00e0001, a basic MSMQ error code which doesn't indicate anything specific.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell so how can I trace this error ?

Comment: Anything in the event logs? The MSMQ diagnostic files are not customer-ready so you may need to raise a support ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: I had a similar error and what I found was that I was trying to change the registry setting for storage path of msmq for w2k8/w2k8r2 which is not supported. Once I changed the storage back to its original value, i was able to start the service.

Comment: I remember that i haven't modified any registry myself. So may be something was messing with my registry.

Comment: What windows are you using?

Comment: I faced this issue on win7 x64. Although this issue is not occurring now.